# OSX: Apple Mail App won't display new lines

Tags: objective-c, macos, email, format, apple-mail

I have the following code that opens apple mail app. This works well except it doesn't display new line properly at all. This is the code I am using.

```
    NSArray *shareItems=@[@"text <br/> text one"];
    NSSharingService *service = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail];
    service.delegate = self;
    [service performWithItems:shareItems];
```

It displays in the Apple mail app like this `text <br/> text one`.
How can I display a new line in the Apple mail app?

Answer (score 0):

You're composing a plain text mail. And thus you must use `\n` for newlines.

If you want to add HTML, you might need to insert a whole HTML document, but it might not work as well, I didn't try it myself.